# Why is no output produced when executing ls?

Tags: c, execvp

I am attempting to write a program that executes whatever is given in argv. However, when I actually run execvp, it is not giving any output, and it isn't producing any errors. This is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char * args[argc];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i) 
        args[i] = strdup(argv[i+1]);
    args[argc-1] = malloc(1);
    *args[argc-1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", args[argc-1]);
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc == 0)
        execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

The output produced when I run ./exec ls is just a single empty line. However, if I run a program which has ls hardcoded into the array, it works fine. Why is this program not listing the contents of the directory?

Comment: And if you give the full path to `ls`? You never check if the calls succeed.

Comment: Why are you duplicating the arguments — there really isn't a need to do so,  And `char args[argc];` is one pointer short of the requirements; you need `char args[argc + 1];` so you can set `args[argc] = NULL;`.  The futzing with `args[argc - 1]` and mallocing a single byte etc is going to confuse things.  You code carefully prints the empty string in `args[argc - 1]` followed by a newline, accounting for what you see.  The `execvp()` fails (but you don't spot this).  It fails because the argument list you pass is not properly null terminated — you must have `args[argc] == NULL`.

Comment: Basic debugging techniques: (1) Check that system calls work; (2) Print arguments to `execvp()` et al before executing the functions. —— Note that I didn't have space to point out that your `for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)` loop ignores the last argument you pass to your program.  That probably isn't helpful, especially if you don't provide any arguments when you run it (so `argc == 1`, so you don't even copy `argv[0]`).

Comment: Also, it isn't clear what benefit you get from the `fork()` — it would work, or fail, the same without it.  The code only ever (indirectly) reports success because there is no `return` before the end of the `main()` function, so it implicitly returns 0 (aka success) every time.

Comment: After @JonathanLeffler 's analysis it sounds secondary, but you also forgot to free pointers allocated with strdup.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, how do you set the last char * to be NULL? The compiler gives a warning about converting to void * without cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretending that it is necessary to duplicate the arguments and to use `fork()`, and observing that if you run:

```
./exec ls
```

then you only want to use arguments from index 1 in the call to `execvp()`, then you end up with code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *args[argc];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
    {
        if ((args[i] = strdup(argv[i+1])) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to allocate memory for '%s'\n",
                    argv[0], argv[i+1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    args[argc-1] = NULL;

    int rc = fork();
    if (rc == 0)
    {
        execvp(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute '%s'\n", argv[0], args[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (rc < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to fork\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The parent process should really `wait()` for the child before exiting itself.  The code should probably include a function to dump the contents of an argument list.  Here's a revised version of the code which doesn't use `strdup()` though it does still fork.  It uses some code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  These simplify the error handling — error reports use a single function call instead of multiple lines of code as before.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc <= 1)
        err_usage("cmd [arg ...]");

    int rc = fork();
    if (rc == 0)
    {
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        err_syserr("failed to execute '%s': ", argv[1]);
    }
    else if (rc < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork: ");

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        if (corpse != rc)
            err_remark("unexpected child PID %d status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
        rc = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        rc = 128 + WTERMSIG(status);
    else
        rc = 255;   /* Something weird happened! */

    return rc;
}
```

Of course, if you don't use `fork()`, you don't need to `wait()` either.  This reduces the code radically:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc <= 1)
        err_usage("cmd [arg ...]");
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    err_syserr("failed to execute '%s': ", argv[1]);
}
```